# Interrupt not responding properly (pigpio)

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, interrupt, interruption, pigpio

I am working on my Raspberry pi-4 with **JavaScript** and **pigpio** module ,i found problems with **interrupt** ,

1. if you **start interruption** (by button for exp )  it **will start a code**  , but if new interruption comes  nothing will happen until the code of the first interruption ends ( **why the interruption has no priority on his own called code !?**)
2. if while loop (infinite one :  like **while (1)** )  exist in the main code the interruption will no longer work !

As far as i know  that **IRQ** interruption **has priority on every thing in code** . but this is not happen !

```js
const Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio;
var i =0 ;

const button = new Gpio(15, {
  mode: Gpio.INPUT,
  pullUpDown: Gpio.PUD_DOWN,
  edge: Gpio.FALLING_EDGE});

button.on('interrupt', (level) => {
  console.log(i+=1)
  rpio.sleep(5)});

// while(1){}
```

Comment: if `rpio.sleep(5)` is blocking (for 5 seconds?), then of course nothing can happen while that is running - javascript has only one thread of execution - why do you need rpio.sleep at all/

Comment: @Bravo It is for my project ... I need to interrupt then go to interruption code  and what ever code it takes time if interruption comes again i need to restart the code again (interrupt the old interruption)

Comment: It makes no sense to block execution - javascript has a single thread of execution, so while execution is blocked, nothing else will run, that's how javascript works - perhaps Python, C or C++ would be a better choice for your project

Comment: @ thanks for your advice , but is there a way to cut off this delay time (at detection external signal , button for exp ) ? i' am electronic engineer  by the way , and as far as i know that IRQ interrupt can stop what ever code is doing then run a function , if the code of interruption is end and there is no new interruption the code return at the same point he stopped from and continue .....

Comment: `IRQ interrupt can stop what ever code is doing` not sure that's compatible with how javascript works though